# How can I get the range between the smallest number and the second smallest number in Common Lisp?

Tags: range, lisp, common-lisp

I am making a function which represents the largest number and the range between the smallest number and the second smallest number in Common Lisp.

This function can make the smallest number and the largest number. (I checked it). But this function can't make the 'the second smallest number' in its list...

Which things should I consider to fix this problem?
I think I fulfilled enough conditions which are necessary to make this function..

I need your big helps. 
This result should be like this :

> (my-range '(0 7 10 2 3 -1)) => (-1 10)

This is my code which I have made.

```
(defun my-range (list-of-numbers)  
    (let ((largest (first list-of-numbers))                 
          (smallest (first list-of-numbers))                  
          (secsmallest (first list-of-numbers)))              
      (dolist (element1 (rest list-of-numbers) largest)      
        (when (> element1 largest)
          (setf largest element1)))
      (dolist (element2 (rest list-of-numbers) smallest)
        (when (< element2 smallest)
          (setf smallest element2)))
      (dolist (element3 (remove smallest list-of-numbers) secsmallest)
        (when (< element3 secsmallest)
          (setf secsmallest element3))
        (return (list (- smallest secsmallest) largest)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the two smallest elements from a list, we can work in one pass. We maintain a list of (up to) the two smallest values we have seen so far. As we scan the items, we insert into this list in order, always throwing away the third smallest value.   When we are done, we have the list of two smallest values. (Or a list of zero values, or of one value, if the list has only that many.)

There is an efficient algorithm for selecting the *k* smallest values out of an uordered list of *n*: [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

If we don't care about incurring *o(n log n)* performance, we can just sort the entire list and pick the first two values from the result.

The situation when we want exactly two items can be hard-coded along these lines:

```
(defun least-two (list)
  (cond
    ((null list) nil)
    ((null (cdr list)) (car list))
    (t (let ((a (car list))
             (b (cadr list)))
       (unless (< a b)
         (rotatef a b))
       (dolist (el (cddr list) (values a b))
         (cond
           ((< el a) (shiftf b a el))
           ((< el b) (setf b el))))))))
```

Very easy: I typed it out in the SE browser editor exactly as you see it, save for two closing parentheses and it seems to be working fine. :)

I took the liberty of using `values` to return multiple values instead of a list. If you want a list, then that has to be changed to `(list a b)`, and also the second case in the main `cond` can should return `list` instead of `(car list)`.

Answer (score 1):

Naive implementation with a single `dolist`:

```
(defun my-range (list-of-numbers)
  ;; I don't know what should be returned if NIL is given
  (check-type list-of-numbers cons)
  (let* ((min (first list-of-numbers))
         (min2 nil)
         (max min))
    (dolist (num (rest list-of-numbers) (list (- min (or min2 max)) max))
      (if (<= num min)
          (setf min2 min
                min num)
          (if (<= max num)
              (setf max num)
              (setf min2 num))))))

(my-range '(0 7 8 2 3 -1))
;=> (-1 8)
(my-range '(-1 0 0 0 0))
;=> (-1 0)
(my-range '(-1 0 0 0 -1))
;=> (0 0)
(my-range '(0))
;=> (0 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just leave efficiency besides and write a working solution first:

Sort a copy of the list to have the smallest elements in front and then select the first two numbers.

```
(defun two-smallest-numbers (input-list)
   (subseq (sort (copy-list input-list) #'<) 0 2))

CL-USER 20 > (two-smallest-numbers '(83 3735 44562 483 83 2223 42232 3322))
(83 83)
```

or return the smallest different numbers: find the smallest, remove it from the list and find the smallest again. Return both numbers.

```
CL-USER 22 > (defun two-smallest-different-numbers (input-list)
               (flet ((smallest-number (list)
                        (reduce #'min list)))
                 (let ((s0 (smallest-number input-list)))
                   (list s0 (smallest-number (remove s0 input-list))))))
TWO-SMALLEST-NUMBERS

CL-USER 23 > (two-smallest-different-numbers '(83 3735 44562 483 83 2223 42232 3322))
(83 483)
```

Comment: Thank you very for your helps!!